# JWT not working with cakephp

Tags: php, jwt, cakephp-3.0

i am trying to implement JWT Authentication to a CakePHP 3. i am following below tutorial:

```
http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-add-jwt-authentication-to-a-cakephp-3-rest-api/
```

i have completed basic setup and it's working good. but when i tried to register a user with the help of Postman it gave me following error:

```
Error: Call to a member function set() on boolean 
File /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/friendsofcake/crud/src/Action/BaseAction.php 
Line: 196
```

my user controller code is:

```
public function add()
    {
        $this->Crud->on('afterSave', function(Event $event) {
            if ($event->subject->created) {
                $this->set('data', [
                    'id' => $event->subject->entity->id,
                    'token' => JWT::encode(
                        [
                            'sub' => $event->subject->entity->id,
                            'exp' =>  time() + 604800
                        ],
                    Security::salt())
                ]);
                $this->Crud->action()->config('serialize.data', 'data');
            }
        });
        return $this->Crud->execute();
    }
```

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found the issue. i have created all templates with cake bake. so in this case i need add Flash to my components list on AppController.